# Android - Widget with AdapterViewFlipper automatic refresh

Tags: android, widget

I am trying to build a widget with AdapterViewFlipper to include many layout in my widget. I am using RemoveViewServices and all is working very well. I want to update automatic widget update on the layouts under Viewflipper but it seems like onUpdate on the WidgetProvider class is not being called.

On a similar question, [Android - Widget with Scrollable Listview Manual Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870263/android-widget-with-scrollable-listview-manual-refresh), people have suggested to call notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged to update the data. I have already implemented this method on refresh button.

I want to specify android:updatePeriodMillis="30000" and wants my widget to updates all layout. All most all the examples I have seen on google using RemoteViewServices, they all have set android:updatePeriodMillis="0". Not sure how to update widget priodically while using RemoveViewServices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check to see what your refresh period is set to. As seen here, the minimum is 30 minutes.

[Android Widget Not Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078122/android-widget-not-updating)